# Is incremental search supported in NSTableView ?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is incremental search supported in NSTableView ? Let's say the NSTableView is focused, and I type "S", is the first row starting with "S" automatically selected ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you are referring to "type selection", i.e. selecting rows by typing characters. This can be activated for a [NSTableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with the [setAllowsTypeSelect:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/setAllowsTypeSelect%3a) method.